# writing in c ,when i use the long double it gives me -0.000000 printing value

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
        
int main()
{
    float first=9876543210987654321.987654321;
    double second=9876543210987654321.987654321;
    long double a=9876543210987654321.987654321;
            
    printf("1=%f",first);
    printf("\n2=%lf",second);
    printf("\n3=%Lf\n\n",a);
    return 0;
}
```

help me
please see the result in the pic attached noob coder xD

[image: its the code result i get]

Comment: Unrelated? the value in the `a` line has type `double`: you want `3.1415L` (or that big monster above) with the `L` suffix.

Comment: No images of code / output please always paste it directly in the question.

Comment: You're using a library that doesn't support long doubles with `Lf`. If you're using MinGW you need to do some tricks. Blame Microsoft.

Comment: What did you expect to get?

Comment: You could try your luck with `#define __USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO 1` before `#include`ing `<stdio.h>`

Comment: *You're using a library that doesn't support long doubles with Lf.*  Which is an extremely hard thing to search for and find the correct answer to, especially for someone new to C.  You pretty much have to know the problem in order to search for the fix, and if you know the problem you'd know the fix already.  I really don't know why questions like this get downvoted so quickly - it's a problem that a new C programmer isn't going to be able to solve.

Comment: @AndrewHenle is it though? "Long double printf wrong value" to google?

Comment: The `printf` in current versions of Microsoft C runtime libraries seems to map both `%lf` and `%Lf` to `long double` arguments, which is non-standard because `%f` and `%lf` are both supposed to map to `double` arguments.

Comment: @anttiHaapala its given in text book of mine

Comment: @AnttiHaapala When I Google that, I get mostly results from using the wrong format - a self-professed "noob" looking through those answers is likely to give up if they don't happen to find the one that fits after about 10-15 that don't help.  The questioner here took the time to create a full MCVE, so a good bit of effort was put into the question, implying a good bit of research trying to find the correct answer.  You really have to know what you're looking for to see the solution to a lot of problems in C, and I think those of us experienced in C have a tendency to forget that - I know I do.

Comment: @AndrewHenle can u help me out?

Comment: @KevinShah Assuming you are using MinGW on Windows, I really don't have any experience using `long double` there.  And if you are on Windows, you have to remember the C runtime is not C99 compliant even with the 21st century more than 20% over, so support for later C features like `long double` is going to be sketchy.

Comment: @KevinShah [You could try your luck with #define __USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO 1 before #includeing <stdio.h>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65846773/writing-in-c-when-i-use-the-long-double-it-gives-me-0-000000-printing-value?noredirect=1#comment116422331_65846773)